# Angularjs karma jasmine undefined is not an object

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

Im trying to start using unit tests in my angularjs project. But get this error and couldnt figure out the problem cause.

fibonacci.service.js

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('myFirstApp').service('FibonacciService', FibonacciService);

  //FibonacciService.$inject = [];
  function FibonacciService() {

    // iterative approach
    this.fibonacci = function (num) {
      var prev1 = 1,
        prev2 = 0,
        current = 0;
      for (var n = 2; n <= num; n++) {
        current = prev1 + prev2;
        prev2 = prev1;
        prev1 = current;
      }
      return current;
    };
    
  }
})();
```

fibonacci.service.tests.js

```js
'use strict';
describe('myFirstApp.FibonacciService', function() {

  var FibonacciService;

  beforeEach(module('myFirstApp'));
  beforeEach(module('app.admin'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    FibonacciService = $injector.get('FibonacciService');
  }));

  it('Should output correct Fibanacci numbers', function() {
    expect(FibonacciService.fibonacci(0)).toBe(0);
    expect(FibonacciService.fibonacci(1)).toBe(1);
    expect(FibonacciService.fibonacci(10)).toBe(55);
  });

});
```

Gruntfile.js

```js
...
karma: {
      unit: {
        options: {
          frameworks: ['jasmine'],
          singleRun: true,
          browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
          files: [
            'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            //'app/scripts/**/*.js'
            //'app/scripts/app.js',
            //'app/scripts/services/fibonacci.service.js',

            'app/scripts/core/core.module.js',
            'app/scripts/core/router.module.js',
            'app/scripts/controllers/admin/admin.module.js',
            'app/scripts/app.js',
            'app/scripts/**/*.js'
            //'app/scripts/services/fibonacci.service.tests.js'

          ]
        }
      }
    }
...
```

```
[4mRunning "karma:unit" (karma) task[24m
[32m13 05 2016 09:13:27.271:INFO [karma]: [39mKarma v0.13.22 server started at http://localhost:9876/
[32m13 05 2016 09:13:27.279:INFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser PhantomJS
[32m13 05 2016 09:13:29.064:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0)]: [39mConnected on socket /#-RzPN-Jcq2NTtD8pAAAA with id 8973102
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
[1A[2KPhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) myFirstApp.FibonacciService Should output correct Fibanacci numbers FAILED
    C:/Users/Denisas/my-yo-project/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4414:53
    forEach@C:/Users/Denisas/my-yo-project/bower_components/angular/angular.js:336:24
    loadModules@C:/Users/Denisas/my-yo-project/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4374:12
    createInjector@C:/Users/Denisas/my-yo-project/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4299:22
    workFn@C:/Users/Denisas/my-yo-project/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2954:60
    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'FibonacciService.fibonacci') in C:/Users/Denisas/my-yo-project/app/scripts/services/fibonacci.service.tests.js (line 13)
    C:/Users/Denisas/my-yo-project/app/scripts/services/fibonacci.service.tests.js:13:28
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.022 secs)
[1A[2KPhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.004 secs / 0.022 secs)
Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

Aborted due to warnings.

Execution Time (2016-05-13 06:13:27 UTC)
karma:unit  2.2s  ██████████████████████████████████████████████████ 100%
Total 2.2s

please help someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code to allow run unit tests successfully as follows:

- Service

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';    
  angular.module('myFirstApp', []).service('FibonacciService', FibonacciService);

  function FibonacciService() {

    // iterative approach
    this.fibonacci = function (num) {

      if (num === 0) {
        return 0;
      }

      if (num === 1) {
        return 1;
      }

      var prev1 = 1,
        prev2 = 0,
        current = 0;

      for (var n = 2; n <= num; n++) {
        current = prev1 + prev2;
        prev2 = prev1;
        prev1 = current;
      }

      return current;
    };
  }
})();
```

- Unit test

```js
'use strict';
describe('myFirstApp.FibonacciService', function () {

  var FibonacciService;

  beforeEach(module('myFirstApp'));
  beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    FibonacciService = $injector.get('FibonacciService');
  }));

  it('Should output correct Fibanacci numbers', function () {
    expect(FibonacciService.fibonacci(0)).toBe(0);
    expect(FibonacciService.fibonacci(1)).toBe(1);
    expect(FibonacciService.fibonacci(10)).toBe(55);
  });
});
```

Comment: wow thanks it works now. But in service i need to use existing module, not to create new.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. I had to load all bower dependancies inside Gruntfile.js